# Trouble with Choice Menu and user generated input

Tags: java

I need to make a program that takes user generated monthly rainfall numbers and and averages them, finds the max and min, finds standard deviation etc. I seem to have most everything down but my "find numbers above and below the average" doesn't seem to be working. Also i cant figure out how to let the user make another choice once they have selected and then been given the desired info. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al2qX.png)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RainfallAnalyzer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double theRainfall = 0;
        double total = 0;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        double[] rainfall = new double[12];

        System.out.println("Enter the rainfall measurements for this year: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < rainfall.length; i++) {
            theRainfall = scan.nextDouble();

            rainfall[i] = theRainfall;
            total += rainfall[i];

        }

        int choiceentry = -1;

        loop:
        while (choiceentry !8) {

            System.out.println("1. print all rainfall measurements");
            System.out.println("2. print the avererage rainfall");
            System.out.println("3. print the maximum and minimum rainfall             measurements");
            System.out.println("4. print the number of months above average rainfall");
            System.out.println("5. print the number of months below average rainfall");
            System.out.println("6. print the median rainfall measurement");
            System.out.println("7. print the standard deviation");
            System.out.println("8. exit");

            if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                choiceentry = scan.nextInt();
            }

            switch (choiceentry) {
                case 1:
                    for (int i = 0; i < rainfall.length; i++) {
                        System.out.println("Month # " + (i + 1) + ": " + rainfall[i]);
                    }
                    break loop;
                case 2:
                    total = total / 12;
                    System.out.println("This year's average rainfall: " + total);
                    break loop;

                case 3:
                    Arrays.sort(rainfall);
                    System.out.println("Min value " + rainfall[0]);
                    System.out.println("Max value " + rainfall[rainfall.length - 1]);
                    break loop;

                case 4:
                    int numRainfallAbove = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < rainfall.length; i++) {
                        if (rainfall[i] >= avg) {
                            numRainfallAbove++;
                        } else {
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Number of months above the average rainfall:   " + numRainfallAbove);
                    break loop;

                case 5:
                    int numRainfallBelow = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < rainfall.length; i++) {
                        if (rainfall[i] <= total) {
                            numRainfallBelow++;
                        } else {
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Number of months below the average rainfall: " + numRainfallBelow);
                    break loop;

                case 6:
                    double median;
                    if (rainfall.length % 2 == 0) {
                        median = ((double) rainfall[rainfall.length / 2] + (double) rainfall[rainfall.length / 2 - 1]) / 2;
                    } else {
                        median = (double) rainfall[rainfall.length / 2];
                    }

                    System.out.println("This year's median rainfall: " + median);

                    break loop;

                case 7:
                    double theDeviation = deviation(rainfall, total);
                    System.out.println("The standard deviation is " + theDeviation);
                    break loop;

            }

        }

    }

    public static double deviation(double[] rainfall, double total) {
        double endResult = 0;
        double temporary = 0;
        double arraySum = 0;
        double average = total;
        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < rainfall.length; i++) {
            sum += Math.pow((rainfall[i] - average), 2);
        }

        temporary = sum / (rainfall.length - 1);
        endResult = Math.sqrt(temporary);
        return endResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've done quite a few things wrong. Stack Overflow has a help center that explains our standards. Here's a sample: [How to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: *"This is my first post so if id did anything wrong in posting this please tell me what i need to do to make my post better. '* - I would add - 1) improve the grammar, punctuation and clarity of your writing. 2) You need to provide a clear statement of your problem.  Vague statements like *"[XXX] doesn't seem to be working"* are not good enough.  How is it not working?  3) Don't put parts of your question as links to images.  Capture the text and copy-paste it into the question.  4) Avoid including irrelevant code.

Comment: And post a title that will relevant to other users. This is not a personal debugging website. Posts are meant to be useful to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code within your case 4:

```
int numRainfallAbove = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < rainfall.length; i++){
if(rainfall[i] >= total){
numRainfallAbove++;
} else{}
}
System.out.println("Number of months above the average rainfall:   "+numRainfallAbove);
break loop;
```

To this:

```
int numRainfallAbove = 0;
double avg = total / 12;
for (int i = 0; i < rainfall.length; i++) {
  if (rainfall[i] >= avg) {
    numRainfallAbove++;
  }
}
System.out.println("Number of months above the average rainfall:   " + numRainfallAbove);
break loop;
```

The issue is that you compare the monthly rainfall to the total instead of the average. You will need to do something similar for your "number of months with below average rainfall".

To make it keep asking for more choices as long as the user doesn't exit, change the while loop to:

`while (choiceentry != 8) {`

As an aside that does not directly relate to your question, try to indent your code properly when you post, and DO NOT use goto statements or breaks which direct to labels.

Comment: nhouser9 thanks for the advice as well as the help.

Comment: Also how do i let the user make another choice rather than having it end the program. I thought the while loop should have made that possible but it seems not.

Comment: And in `case 2:`, do not change the `total`. If you want to print the `average` just change `System.out.println("This year's average rainfall: " + total);` to `System.out.println("This year's average rainfall: " + total / 12);`. You also find `min` and `max` when user enter `theRainFall` in first `for` loop, store `min` and `max` by their index or value.

Comment: `Also how do i let the user make another choice rather than having it end the program. I thought the while loop should have made that possible but it seems not`. Remove `loop` and change condition of `while` to `while (choiceentry != 8)`

Comment: @BlakeBrennan Dang Khoa's comment is a good answer to your question. Generally, if someone's answer helps its nice to upvote or accept it as an answer to reward them for taking the time to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just got back to this thread. Thank you Dang Khoa for the help!

Comment: One more thing @nhouser9 and @ Dang Khoa, so everything works great the first time through but when i continue to run the program without exiting it the,measured numbers seem to change. For instance if i choose to find the numbers above average first, it works fine but say i ask for the average and standard deviation before i ask for the above average , the numbers will be wrong on not only the numbers above average but everything else as well. Again thank you for all the help y'all have given me. It is much appreciated

Comment: @BlakeBrennan that is because when you compute the average you actually MODIFY the total variable. the next time you loop it will still be modified. Try storing the average in a different var

Answer (score 0):

> Also i cant figure out how to let the user make another choice once they have selected and then been given the desired info.

Well the way you have written the code, is says (in effect)

```
  loop: while not a valid choice:
    get a choice
    if it is valid choice":
      act on it 
      break out of loop
```

(Note the "belt and braces" way you are terminating the loop is ... unnecessary.  It is clearest to put the termination condition in the `while` condition *only*.)

So what you actually need is a way for the user to say "I want to stop now".  So you could make that another choice, or you could say that an *invalid* choice is required.

Then you need to change the loop to say

```
 while a valid choice:
```

or

```
 while not the stop choice (or condition):
```

One point, have you considered what happens if you the user enters "STOP" or something else that isn't a number?  Try it.  Then try to explain what is actually happening.

Comment: Thank you Stephen!